# Auth::user() return null in route non authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-api

I've route api without middleware

I want to access Auth::user() in my controller but Auth::user always return null,
Here my api route and my controller:

---

```
Route::get('products/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'show']);
```

---

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Product $product) {

        Log::debug(Auth::user()); // return null 
        Log::debug(Auth::guard('api')->user()); // return null
        Log::debug(auth('sanctum')->user()); // return null

    }
}
```

---

What i want to expected it's:

1. When not login user can be access data product like:

   `products: { name, price }`
2. When user login can access data product like:

   `products: { name, price, product_me}`

I've been tried some reference with no lucky,
Need other references to solve this problem,
Thanks

Comment: what do you get using `request()->user('sanctum')`?

Comment: As you mention you have  route api without middleware that means you and not passing authentication token to API and its not getting validated so you will not get any user from auth , you must have to use middleware and authentication for it

Comment: Hi zahid, I've tried your solution but still return null

Comment: are you passing the access_token with the request??

Comment: Hi @SagarSainkar, Yeah i must adding middleware auth:api/auth:sanctum for getting the Auth:user, but need login for access that endpoint. while in my case has a data product without authentication, to the point authenitacated its optional for access data product

Comment: Wow @zahidhasanemon, got lucky here, it worked when im passing access_token to header :D

Comment: how can you get the user without the token?? send the access token when user is authenticated to get the user.